# Random "permission denied" error while writing a file from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, permission-denied, filesystemobject

That's my first time posting on stackoverflow. I've been finding usefull answers on this site but this time, I can't find no help with this problem.

### General context

I wrote a VBScript Toolkit script (S:\Universe_bo\prod\batch\BO\libs\PXI_Toolkit.vbs) included in scripts (S:\Universe_bo\prod\batch\BO*.wsf) that are executed by a scheduler software.

The system is a Windows Server 2003 server (this server is part of an active-passive Windows cluster and the S: drive is a resource of this cluster). The Windows user running the scripts has permission to write in the directory and is an Administrator.

In the scripts, I open a new file and write some text in it (it is the content of an e-mail).

### The problem

Here is what happens (today, it crashed 7 out of 10 times):

> (---) [24/03/2012 10:34:23] Ouverture du fichier [S:\universe_bo\prod\data\email_rad98038.tmp]
>   S:\universe_bo\prod\batch\BO\BOLANC_BOAPP500_TOP100.wsf(2451, 8) Erreur d'exécution Microsoft VBScript: Permission refusée

It means "Runtime error Microsoft VBScript: Permission denied".

The line 2451 from the script is the following:

```
Set objFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(_
      pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail, _
      ForWriting, _
      True)
```

We have been using them for two years without a problem on the test server (not a cluster) but now that it finally passed production, it doesn't work all the time.

I have no idea what the problem could be, I'm all ears and will take any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Guillaume

## Source scripts

### .wsf script

The .wsf scripts look like this:
(I removed the irrelevant parts, and comments are in French since we are)

```
'===============================================================================
' BOLANC_BOAPP500_TOP100.wsf (script)
'===============================================================================
<job><?job debug="true"?>
<script language="VBScript" src="libs/PXI_Toolkit.vbs"/>
<script language="VBScript">
Dim codeRetour ' Le code retour du script
codeRetour = 0 ' est initialisé à 0 (tout va bien)

' [...]
' Irrelevant stuff
' [...]

' Exécuter le rapport
codeRetour = rapport.Executer


LibererRessources
Wscript.Quit codeRetour
</script>
</job>
```

### Toolkit script

And here are the involved parts of the PXI_Toolkit.vbs script:

```
Option Explicit
'===============================================================================
' PXI_Toolkit.vbs (script)
'===============================================================================


'*******************************************************************************
' fso (objet)
'       Scripting.FileSystemObject
'*******************************************************************************
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'*******************************************************************************
' Constantes pour l'ouverture des fichiers
'*******************************************************************************
Private Const ForReading = 1 ' Ouvre un fichier en lecture seule. 
Private Const ForWriting = 2 ' Ouvre un fichier en écriture.
Private Const ForAppending = 8 ' Ouvre un fichier et permet l'écriture à la fin
                               ' du fichier.

'*******************************************************************************
' WshShell (objet)
'       Objet Permettant d'accéder aux fonctionnalités systèmes Windows.
'*******************************************************************************
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'*******************************************************************************
' WshSysEnv (tableau de chaînes)
'       Tableau contenant les variables d'environnements. WshSysEnv est indexé
'       par le nom des variables qu'il contient.                            
'       Exemple : Ecrire "Utilisateur="& WshSysEnv("USERNAME")
'*******************************************************************************
Dim WshSysEnv
Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")

' Lots of stuff

'*******************************************************************************
' EcrireErr (procédure)
'       Affiche un message d'erreur.
'
' Paramètres :
' - pstrMessage (chaîne)
'       Message d'erreur à afficher.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub EcrireErr(pstrMessage)
  WScript.stdErr.WriteLine "(!!!) ["& Now &"] "& Cstr(pstrMessage)
End Sub ' EcrireErr

'*******************************************************************************
' EcrireLog (procédure)
'       Journalise un message dans les logs.
'
' Paramètres :
' - pstrChaine (chaîne)
'       Texte à journaliser.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub EcrireLog(pstrChaine)
  Ecrire "(---) ["& Now &"] "& Cstr(pstrChaine)
End Sub ' EcrireLog

'*******************************************************************************
' LibererRessources (procédure) 
'       Libère les ressources potentiellement ouvertes au cours de l'exécution
'       des fonctions de ce script.
'
' Paramètres : Aucun
'*******************************************************************************
Sub LibererRessources()
  EcrireLog "LibererRessources"

  ' Libérer les variables système
  Set WshArguments = Nothing
  Set WshSysEnv = Nothing
  Set WshShell = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub ' LibererRessources

Class ClsRapportBO
  Private pvarrstrMessageEmail pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail

  Public Function Executer()
    ' Ecriture du fichier contenant le corps du mail
    If Not IsEmpty(pvarrstrMessageEmail) Then
      Dim objFichier, strLigne

      EcrireLog "Ouverture du fichier ["& pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail &"]"
      Set objFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(_
          pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail, _
          ForWriting, _
          True)

      ' Ecriture de l'en-tête du message
      objFichier.WriteLine "Bonjour"
      objFichier.WriteLine

      ' Lecture des éléments du tableau construire le fichier
      For Each strLigne In pvarrstrMessageEmail
        objFichier.WriteLine strLigne
      Next

      ' Ecriture du pied de page
      objFichier.WriteLine 
      objFichier.WriteLine "NB : Ce message est envoyé automatiquement. "&_
                           "Merci de ne pas y répondre."

      objFichier.Close
    End If

    ' More stuff

    If Not IsEmpty(pvarrstrMessageEmail) And fso.FileExists(pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail) Then
      EcrireLog "Suppression du fichier ["& pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail &"]"
      fso.DeleteFile(pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail)
    End If
  End Function ' Executer
End Class ' ClsRapportBO

Function CreerRapportBO(pstrChemin, parrstrInvites, pstrToken)
  Dim objRapport

  Set objRapport = new ClsRapportBO
  ' ...
  Set CreerRapportBO = objRapport
End Function ' CreerRapportBO

' Tests de la boîte à outils
Sub TestsUnitaires()
  ' Unit tests...
End Sub ' TestsUnitaires
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "S:\universe_bo\prod\data\email_rad98038.tmp" a file created by the script, or a file created by another process? A likely cause of this problem is that the file is in use. You can wrap the statement with:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objFichier = fso.OpenTextFile(_
  pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail, _
  ForWriting, _
  True)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsObject(objFichier) Then
...
More Logic Here
...
End If
```

Comment: "S:\universe_bo\prod\data\email_rad98038.tmp" is the file created by the script. Its name is supposed to be created uniquely and is stored in the pvstrNomFichierCorpsEmail variable.
Thanks for the idea to add the error checking, I'll use this to debug the script.

Comment: You are using the third boolean attribute to create the text file if it does not exist so you can't be getting an error because of a missing file.  The only other source of this error is if the file cannot be opened for writing as suggested.  If the file is not read-only, then it is likely in use.  The suggested error handling will get you around the error, but you will need to decide what to do instead.  You might try sleeping for a bit to see if the file becomes available, or you might write to an alternate log file instead.

Comment: This was it: the given file was already opened by another script.
The real problem was that the method GetTempName from FileSystemObject returned the same temporary file name for two scripts run in parallel. They both tried to create the same file at the same time hence the problem.

I now create my temp file names using GUIDs and it should work like a charm.

Thanks natemrice!